# Hide Label Google map

Tags: css, google-maps, label

Is there also a way to hide with css the entire label that says "do you own this website?"

[image]

Comment: Probably all you have to do is to leave the development mode. But without code we cannot help you. Why don't you press ok or "Do you own this website"? It seems like this message is directed to you, the developer.

Comment: it requires an api key to do so! the idea is only remove the error label without purchasing the api to google! the water mark is no problem, but the label is huge!

Comment: Sure, why don't you just get one? There is no way around it. AFAIK they are free as long as you don't receive millions of requests.

Comment: allready managed  to remove "do you own this website" and google logo with: a[href^="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors"]{display:none !important}
img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_gray.svg"]{display:none !important}    to be perfect i need  code to replace the text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**so for delete "do you own this website" i've used:**

```
a[href^="developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/…{display:none !important}
```

**to delete google logo i've used:**

```
img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_gray.svg"]{display:none !important}
```

**to delete "Não é possivel carregar correctamente o Google maps nesta página" i've used:**

```
.pvw-title span {
  display: none;
}
```

and put the class inside map div .php page

**and to delete "ok" button i've used:**

```
.dismissButton {  display: none; 
        background:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, but in case someone needs a terrible temporary workaround, can use:

```js
    google.maps.event.addListener(YOUR_GMAP_OBJECT, 'tilesloaded', function(){
        // Once map object is rendered, hide gmaps warning (billing account)
        // And consider migrating to a different engine, or paying for gmaps
        $(".dismissButton").click();
    });
```